# Does the solvent used affect basic strength?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

In [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47582/nucleophilicity-basicity-in-protic-and-aprotic-solvents) question, it is explained how basicity and nucleophilicity are different and how the solvent used affects nuclephilicity.

What I wondered was whether there would be a difference in the basic strength of say $\ce{Cl-}$ in $\ce{H2O}$ (a protic solvent) and $\ce{DMSO}$ (an aprotic solvent).

My answer would be that due to solvation in $\ce{H2O}$, the $\ce{Cl-}$ ions would get stabilised and hence their basic strength would reduce as compared to those ions which are dissolved in $\ce{DMSO}$.

Am I right in saying this or did I overlook something?

Comment: I think you could more explicit by considering the differential stabilization of the species (i.e., $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ versus $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ for a better answer.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you're trying to say, could you rephrase that somehow?

Comment: The basicity you're talking about is thermodynamic, so you should look at the products versus reactants for the acid-base reaction. You can't just say, oh the of the reactants (the base) is stabilized more than the other, because the product (conjugate acid) could be equally stablized.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for explaining @Zhe

Comment: Solvents like DMSO or DMF because of the exposed oxygen supposedly solvate cations more efficiently than anions. Bases such as tertiary butoxide are more reactive in DMSO solutions. Solubility is a concern for a simple ionic such as NaCl.  You might research the effect of DMSO on reactions with LiCl or anhydrous HCl or salts that might be more soluble such as tetramethylammonium chloride.